# What are the supported backend filesystems (storage pools) for OpenEBS Jiva Volumes?

Tags: openebs

What are the filesystems on the node mount-points on which Jiva replicas can be created.

Answer (score 0):

Jiva uses sparse files as disks to store data, which in turn requires filesystem support for extent mapping (i.e., the fiemap ioctl). A list of commonly used filesystem with extent support includes: ext4, xfs, btrfs, lustre. Popular OS/Storage filesystems that don't have this support include: ZFS, NFS, Amazon EFS.

ext4 is being extensively used as a supported jiva backend in production."